# facebox-jquery problem in chrome and safari

Tags: ajax, jquery, google-chrome, facebox

Facebox is a jQuery-based, Facebook-style lightbox which can display images, divs, or entire remote pages.

But, in Chrome and Safari you'll can have a bad experiencie when displaying post-submit form (the response).

test here with Chrome: http://www.freecss.info/tutorial/contact/index.html

"submitemail.php" (the response) is displayed in a new page {problem}, with firefox and IE7 it is displayed in the same modal window.

Any hint is so apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved.

Never put < html > and/or < body > tags to the remote file (html, php) what contains the modal-form :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove  and  tag from the remote page(or file)